# Does sklearn provide a VotingClassifier for already fit estimators?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have n binary classifiers, and I'd like to see what results I get by combining their predictions, just like a `VotingClassifier` would do, using majority voting or the sum of the individual predict_proba to determine the final prediction.

(Looking on google I already found [here](https://gist.github.com/tomquisel/a421235422fdf6b51ec2ccc5e3dee1b4) some guy's implementation of what I need and the code seems correct, I'm just looking for the "sklearn way" of achieving this)

My problem is that `sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier` is a Soft Voting/Majority Rule classifier for **unfitted** estimators.

**Does sklearn provide something for **fitted** estimators?**

By looking at `sklearn.ensemble`'s [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble) it would seem it does not, but isn't weird that such a functionality would be missing from such a complete library? Am I missing something? Can I get that functionality using features from sklearn or do I have to implement it by myself?

Comment: I'd like to point out that the code I found doesn't work when, like in my case, the classifier doesn't output a number but a string like "in" / "out"

Comment: Why do you have to use sklearn?

Comment: It's been a while but it was just for having a convenient interface and because all the project was built around `sklearn`. I saw there already was a `VotingClassifier` and it felt weird that there wasn't one able to work with already fit classifiers

Answer (score 2):

No, as of May 2023, there is no support in sklearn for a voting classifier made of pre-built models.